# Unable to Import Postgresql Database into Amazon AWS Database

Tags: restore, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have a Postgresql 9.3 database locally which needs to be 'restored' to an Amazon AWS database. I am able to restore this database to various local Postgresql servers but on Amazon, using pgAdminIII client, the import gives various errors like:

```
ERROR: must be owner of extension plpgsql
```

or

```
Unable to run language 'c'
```

My best guess is that the database has objects which have different users and their permissions but executing on the Amazon database don't allow those permissions to work. I have tried to create an empty database on Amazon and then give full access to various users but no avail.

What can I do, in pgAdminIII locally to somehow dump the whole database into an .sql or a .backup file and then restore on Amazon? I have good luck in exporting to .backup file and then restoring on non-Amazon databases.

Note: I am logging in as a user under 'superuser' group on Amazon and have no problem creating new databases.

Thanks!

Comment: The AWS RDS PostgreSQL "superuser" isn't really a PostgreSQL superuser at all. For reasons of RDS security it can't create `C` language extensions and doesn't own built-in extensions. The error about PL/PgSQL won't be a problem most likely, but if you're using C extensions you may be in trouble. Perhaps you need to `CREATE EXTENSION ... FROM UNPACKAGED` for one or more extensions you installed directly with the `.sql` files in a prior PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Craig: You sound right. There are some PostGIS extensions installed via .sql files on the local server and, during the restore to Amazon, they are perhaps being created again? Anyway, my supervisor was able to make this work through some Amazon RDS 'console' and I'll ask him soon..